# Azure Synapse - Where to find the Managed identity object ID

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-link

Hopefully a quick question

I was wondering from within Azure Synapse Studio - where can I find the "Managed identity object ID"?

I tried to click around before and was some what able to find it when creating an integration dataset - But I cant seem to find like a high level overview screen with for example the Managed identity object ID or managed ID.

I know these can be found quite easily from within the Azure portal but I cant seem to find the same info easily within Azure Synapse Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Azure portal -> Azure synapse -> properties**

[image: Ref1]

or

> **Azure synapse studio**

If you are trying to create linked service, you will find managed identity object ID.

[image: Ref2]

Comment: Ah! I wish it was as easily found from within Azure Synapse Studio - I was digging around and couldnt find it, I didnt know you had to do a "selection" (authentication type drop down) to get it to show up - Just curious is that the only spot it shows up in Azure Synapse Studio? - Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @rodneyc8063 for the comment, another alternative way is there to get managed identity object ID